# Xulrunner fails to launch MyApp

Tags: xul, xulrunner

My latest attempt at a workable configuration (Win32) is this one found on kodewerx.org: http://www.kodewerx.org/wiki/A_Brief_Introduction_To_XULRunner:_Part_2  [dated 2010].

My config is as follows:

```
c:\program files\xulrunner\xulrunner.exe  ..et all..
c:\program files\myapp\application.ini
```

I have added c:\program files\xulrunner to the system PATH.
From the command prompt xulrunner.exe executes and throws up its default help page.
So xulrunner.exe runs.

I have used Mozilla's Dev Org app for jump starting add on development: http://www.mozdev.org/projects/wizard/

I used a Application configurator which has provided me with a large number of files, in a typical moz/chrome layout.

```
c:\Program Files\MyApp\application.ini
c:\Program Files\MyApp\defaults\preferences\prefs.js
c:\Program Files\MyApp\chrome.manifest
c:\Program Files\MyApp\chrome\content\[*.xul|*.js]
c:\Program Files\MyApp\chrome\locale\en-US\*.dtd
c:\Program Files\MyApp\chrome\skin\*.css
```

I am uncertain about the minimum/maximum Gecko versions to specifiy at the current date: I have this for the moment, in application.ini:

```
[App]
Name=MyApp
ID=myapp@stainsby.ca
Version=0.1
BuildID=0001
Vendor=Stainsby

[Gecko]
MinVersion=1.9.2.0
MaxVersion=28.0.*
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, what happens when you try to start your application? You forgot to describe the actual issue...